# centre an image in the middle of a panel

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am coming to grips with Graphics in Java and created a circle on a JPanel.
How would a center the circle in the JPanel?

```
package exerciseninetwo;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;    

public class ExerciseNineTwo extends JFrame
{
    public ExerciseNineTwo()
    {
        super("My Frame");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(new CanvasPanel());

        setVisible(true);        
    }        

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new ExerciseNineTwo();
    }
}
class CanvasPanel extends JPanel
{        
    CanvasPanel()
    {
        setSize(120, 120);            
        //setBackground(Color.cyan);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D comp = (Graphics2D)g;
        Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Float(200, 200, 200, 200);
        comp.draw(circle);

        comp.setColor(Color.cyan);
        comp.fillRect(0,0,500,500);

        comp.setClip(circle);
        comp.setColor(Color.magenta);
        comp.fillRect(0,0,500,500);           
    }
}
```

Comment: `ExerciseNineTwo` Is this [tag:homework]?

Comment: unrelated to your question, a couple of comments to CanvasPanel: a) its paintComponent implementation violates super's opaqueness contract if its size is > 500, 500 (to remedy, _always_ call super.paintComponent) b) calling setSize in its constructor has no effect (actual sizing is the job of its parent's layoutManager)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just draw it in the middle of your panel.

```
float x = getWidth()/2 - ELLIPSE_WIDTH/2;
float y = getHeight()/2 - ELLIPSE_HEIGHT/2;
Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, ELLIPSE_WIDTH, ELLIPSE_HEIGHT);
```

Answer (score 3):

Take the panel object and query the X and Y size parameters(, or width and height). Divide each by 2 will give you the center of the frame. Create a circle using the result as the X and Y coordinates.

like

```
float x = (width-width of oval) /2;
float y = (height-height of oval) /2;
```

now set the x and y in the constructor of eclipse

Answer (score 3):

Use `getWidth()/getHeight()` of the panel.

```
int x=(getWidth()-ovalWidth)/2;
int y=(getHeight()-ovalHeight)/2;
```

Check that panel width is bigger than oval width, and the same with height.

Answer (score 2):

You may easily get the size of your panel and place the circle accordingly:

```
Dimension size = getSize();
Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Float(
    (size.width - 200) / 2,       // -200 due to the width/height of the circle
    (size.height - 200) / 2, 
    200, 200);
```